# I'm having trouble finishing a simple JS math game

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I got my `onclick` function working, but the issue is that jQuery wasn't working for me for some reason, so I took it out, but I don't know how to disable the `onclick` without using jQuery: how can I disable the button's `onclick` and have it stay disabled if it is correct (and reset if it isn't correct? I also need to make it so that `numOne` and `numTwo` recalculate another random number if it is equal to the id of a disabled button, so I'm guessing I have change the `do while` loop I have to make sure that `numTwo` never equals `numOne`, but I'm not sure how to do all that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lemon Squares - Grade 1 Edition</title>
    </head>
    <body id="bodyId">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var button = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);
            var numbers = new Array();  
            for (var i=0; i<16; i++)
            {
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
                numbers[i] = document.createElement("button");
                numbers[i].innerHTML = button[randomNumber];
                numbers[i].setAttribute("type", "button");
                numbers[i].setAttribute("id", button[i]);
                numbers[i].setAttribute("onclick", "onClick('" + button[randomNumber] + "')");
                numbers[i].setAttribute("value", button[randomNumber]);
                document.getElementById("bodyId").appendChild(numbers[i]);
                if (i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11) 
                {
                document.write("<br>");
                }
            }
            var numOne = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*15)).toString();
            var numTwo = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*15)).toString();
            do
            {
                numTwo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*15).toString();
            }
            while (numTwo == numOne);
            var numberOne = document.getElementById(numOne).value;
            var numberTwo = document.getElementById(numTwo).value;
            var answer = parseInt(numberOne) + parseInt(numberTwo);
            var total = 0
            function onClick(x)
            {
                x = parseInt(x);
                total += x;
                if (total > answer)
                {
                alert("Sorry, try again.")
                total = 0
                }
                else if(total == answer)
                {
                alert("Congratulations, you did it!");
                total = 0
                }        
            }       
            document.write("<br> Pick two numbers that add up to: " + answer);
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, the buttons had stopped responding when I had added jquery. So I took it out.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are going about this the wrong way.

the logic of the game is (if i understand correctly):

- pick "1 to n"(n is the count of all available buttons/items) number of items randomly
- get the sum of the selected items value and show to user
- record and add up the user selected values until the goal is reached and keep track of the selected items by user is an a array
- if the selected items sum is correct disable the selected (just add disabled attribute to the button) items and reaped from step 1 where n is the number of remaining items

so for your problem :

on every button click take these steps :

1. add the value to a array
2. get the sum of values in the array
3. compare the sum with the answer

   - if the sum is less than the answer do nothing and wait for the next click
   - if the sum is equal to the answer

     1. disable the buttons in the array
     2. clear the selected items array
     3. create a new answer
   - if the sum is more than the answer clear the selected items array and start over

i hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was trying to do that this morning but I had trouble adding the value to the array, well I've been having trouble getting the value from any of my button clicks to anything.  I definitely think I'll be able to do the rest once I get past that obstacle. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'll post some examples of code I've tried using once I get home.